# How to set width to the container div while creating a bootstrap responsive layout?

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am trying to make a bootstrap responsive layout. Here What I am trying is to short the width of the main container div. I tried setting width inline, but the layout lost its responsive nature. When I checked the bootstrap.css, the width for the container div is given auto. I would really appreciate if anyone can reveal the logic behind this. Following is the demo code of bootstrap.

PS - I don't want to shorten the width of the navbar-fixed class, I just want to shorten the width of the container without losing the responsiveness .

### HTML

```
<div class="navbar navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="btn btn-navbar" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nav-collapse">
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </a>
      <a class="brand" href="#">Project name</a>
      <div class="nav-collapse">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
          <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container" >

  <!-- Main hero unit for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
  <div class="hero-unit">
    <h1>Hello, world!</h1>
    <p>This is a template for a simple marketing or informational website. It includes a large callout called the hero unit and three supporting pieces of content. Use it as a starting point to create something more unique.</p>
    <p><a class="btn btn-primary btn-large">Learn more &raquo;</a></p>
  </div>

  <!-- Example row of columns -->
  <div class="row">
    <div class="span4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
       <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
    <div class="span4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
       <p>Donec id elit non mi porta gravida at eget metus. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus. Etiam porta sem malesuada magna mollis euismod. Donec sed odio dui. </p>
      <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
   </div>
    <div class="span4">
      <h2>Heading</h2>
      <p>Donec sed odio dui. Cras justo odio, dapibus ac facilisis in, egestas eget quam. Vestibulum id ligula porta felis euismod semper. Fusce dapibus, tellus ac cursus commodo, tortor mauris condimentum nibh, ut fermentum massa justo sit amet risus.</p>
      <p><a class="btn" href="#">View details &raquo;</a></p>
    </div>
  </div>

  <hr>

  <footer>
    <p>&copy; Company 2012</p>
  </footer>

</div>
```

### CSS

```
  .container,
  .navbar-fixed-top .container,
  .navbar-fixed-bottom .container {
    width: 1170px;
  }
  .container {
    width: auto;
  }
```

### Screenshot

[Screenshot http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/7074/testjxk.jpg](http://img442.imageshack.us/img442/7074/testjxk.jpg)

Comment: try width in percentage.

Comment: try using percentage or auto width.

Comment: I have tried that already, it works when I do it inline but its not working when I do it from the style sheet, Is there anyway to achieve this without inline ?

Comment: @Bala.C would you say this question is answered?

Answer (score 8):

In the bootstrap-responsive.css file you will find code blocks, known as media queries, like

```
@media (max-width: 480px) {
  /* Your CSS here */
}
```

and

```
@media (min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 980px) {
  /* Your CSS here */
}
```

You can set the width of content area to the appropriate width for each screen width inside of these blocks without affecting the other blocks.

Answer (score 4):

try this

```
  .container {
    width: auto;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-right: 200px;
  }​
```

Comment: @Bala.C increase the 200px so that you can see the effect

Answer (score 0):

To make it look responsive you could create `#page-wrap` and use `max-width: 1200px; margin: 0 auto;` or you could apply it only to the content. so it would look like this

### HTML

```
<div ID="page-wrap">
 <!-- CONTENT -->
</div>
```

### CSS

```
#page-wrap {
 max-width: 1200px;
 margin: 0 auto;
}
```